# Points Disappearing When Applying Categorised Symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

I am new to QGIS (and GIS in general).

I have imported a CSV file containing approx 1500 points with lat/long co-ordinates. I applied categorised symbology based on a field in the attribute table, and that worked with no issues, so I now have points with various colours based on the values in a field:

[image]

I am now trying to amend some of the data in the attribute table so that I can move some points from one category into another category.

As this layer is based on a .csv file, I am unable to edit the attribute table. I read some posts where people had recommended saving a copy of the layer as a Shapefile or a Geopackage, to allow editing of the attribute table.

So I have done this, but this removes the original categorised symbology and all of the points are back to one colour in the new layer:

[image]

I then try to re-apply the categorised symbology to this new layer as follows:

[image]

...but as soon as I click 'Apply' or 'OK', the points disappear from the map:

[image]

I am not sure what the issue is or what I am doing wrong, does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Did you click 'Classify' button before 'Apply'?

Comment: I didn't! I have now and that has fixed it, I am so silly. Apologies and thank you for the help :)

Comment: Even easier: copy the style of the old (CSV) layer to the new (Geopackage) layer: right-click CSV layer `Style / Copy Style` and right-click Geopackage layer `Style / Paste Style`